# oddity (IMHO) in regex (JS) to add 2 whitespace between comma and one digit number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a really really simple string like that:

```
data="1,2,3,4,5,"
```

I want to add TWO spaces before one digit numbers.

So I use this "really really simple" regex:

```
data = data.replace(/,\s*(\d),/g,",  $1,");
```

But the output is:

```
"1,  2,3,  4,5"
```

See: 
http://tinyurl.com/a8njw65

I am totally confused. To me IT MUST WORKS :D I dont find any error. But it does not work so I reached a deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

It does work.  You're including the comma after the 2 in the regular expression, which means that comma can't be part of the next match of the regular expresson.

Comment: Yes, now I know. I miss this theoretical construct. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

`"1,24,3,4,56".replace(/,\s*(\d)(?=,|$)/g,",  $1");`

Comment: Thank you also to you, this is the 4th flavour :D It works great.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the expression consumes the `,` and the next match will not find it. To solve it you can use lookarounds. For example:

```
"1,24,3,4,56".replace(/,\s*(\d)(?!\d)/g,",  $1");
"1,24,3,4,56".replace(/,\s*(?=\d(?!\d))/g,",  ");
"1,24,3,4,56".replace(/,\s*(?=\d(,|$))/g,",  ");
```

Comment: Thank you, all works. And I have got my mistake, thank you again.